# SSIS - Script + Process task to pass values to Parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS Package that has a process task to be executed which internally executes a *.bat file.

The *.bat file has a few steps that are executed.I want to feed in some of the values in the batch file as parameters %1,%2 etc

I have the structure like the following:

-username %1 -p%2

I want to pass values dynamically to this process task using a script task that would be present before the process task.

[image]

Please let know how this can be achieved

Answer (score 4):

`Execute Process Task` has `Arguments` property, which can be set dynamically via `Expressions`.

1. Store parameters values in variables, e.g. `Param1` and `Param2`
2. Select `Expressions` property of `Execute Process Task` and create new expression: `Property` = `Arguments` and `Expression` similar to `"-username " + @[User::Param1]  + " -p" + @[User::Param2]`. If params aren't strings you should cast them to strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there also a step by step tutorial that will help with this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/6b893df2-cc15-4f28-93f1-aa798e8bf9fd

Comment: @Gallop with which part do you have problem?

Comment: The script task and how to use the defined values to the process file and configuring the bat file to take the inputs

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Using Variables in script task: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx How to use set variables you have in the answer already. Hot to use parameters in bat: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php