# How to read parameter from navision to batch file and pass the parameter to ssis package

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have a requirement where Navision will send a parameter to a batch file and that parameter will read in ssis package.

My batch files is not reading variable value from Navision.

In my batch file I have written like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
DTEXEC /FILE "D:\rambabu\BelliniSSIS\Integration Services Project1\Package3Poc.dtsx" /SET "\package.Variables[User::pos].Properties[Value]";

pause
```

Can anyone help me in fixing the issue?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [SSIS - Script + Process task to pass values to Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12671034/3959875) - follow the steps in the answer and then in your batch file use `%1` for the first parameter, `%2` - second and so on.

Comment: how t o read the parameter from Navision to batch file

Comment: @vinaykumar which variable?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it answer exactly your question but is good to know; You can use DTEXECUI like is explained [here](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/07/31/using-dtexecui-to-generate-a-dtexec-command-line-statement-the-easy-way/) to generate your command line.